# Using the csv module

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I am using the csv module to create a file then write to it. However, nothing is being written to the .csv file.

Here is my code:

```
import csv
with open('eggsandham.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: A more descriptive title would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case this code is working and writing to a csv file in current directory . Output or file is :

May be try giving absolute path

Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam |Baked Beans|
Spam |Lovely Spam| |Wonderful Spam|

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code:

```
>>> with open('/host/rk/Python27/eggsandham.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
...     spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ' ',quotechar = '|', quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
...     spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
...     spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam','Wonderful Spam'])
```

It produces output like this:

```
Spam Spam Spam Spam Spam |Baked Beans|
Spam |Lovely Spam| |Wonderful Spam|
```

in the.csv file